# Specifying the order of encoding in Ordinal Encoder

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, categorical-data

I'm using OrdinalEncoder, and I cannot find how to specify the encoding order. I mean that I have categories like "bad", "average", "good" which naturally have an order. But I want to specify that order, since the encoder cannot know itself the meaning of categories. Indeed, with  categories='auto', some categories are encoded in wrong direction with respect to some others and I do not want this because I know, at least for some of them, if the correlation is positive or negative.

But specifying the categories results in an error during fitting:

> 'OrdinalEncoder' object has no attribute 'handle_unknown'.

If I do not specify the categories, fitting process goes well, and I do not understand why (the attribute "categories_", after fitting, shows me the same categories I enter by hand when I try to specify them).

I specify the categories as a list of lists. Here what happens without specifying categories.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import OrdinalEncoder

df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([['a','a','a'], ['b','c','c']]).transpose())
oE = OrdinalEncoder(categories='auto')
oE.fit(df)

print(oE.categories_)
```

Resulting in: `[array(['a'], dtype=object), array(['b', 'c'], dtype=object)]`

Specifying categories explicitely:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([['a','a','a'], ['b','c','c']]).transpose())
oE = OrdinalEncoder(categories=[['a'], ['b', 'c']])
oE.fit(df)
```

The result is this error:

> > Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 3, in 
>       oE.fit(df)
>
> File
>   "/home/alessio/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/_encoders.py",
>   line 774, in fit
>       self._fit(X)
>
> File
>   "/home/alessio/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/_encoders.py",
>   line 85, in _fit
>       if self.handle_unknown == 'error':
>
> AttributeError: 'OrdinalEncoder' object has no attribute
>   'handle_unknown'

Comment: From which line do you get this error? -> `'OrdinalEncoder' object has no attribute 'handle_unknown'.`

Comment: From ordEnc.fit(dataframe)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. This is bug in scikit-learn, already fixed and added to version 0.20.1, which is still not released. 
https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/12365

I solved it temporarily by copying fixed `_encoders.py` to my project and using.

```
from _encoders import OrdinalEncoder
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Tomas, at least I know it's not my fault! But copying _encoders.py in my folder does not work:
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package